# Why is my application state not updating (redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am following the redux counter tutorial from the official docs,- but my applications state is seemingly not updating. To be more clear, essentially the application is a counter with an increment button and a decrement button and it displays the current value on the screen.

I can get it to console log the value as it changes, but it doesn't output it on the screen. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';


const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state -1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
const store = createStore(counter);
store.subscribe(()=>{
  console.log(store.getState());
});
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Counter Application</h1>
        <hr/>

        <Counter 
          value={store.getState()}
          onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})} 
          onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'})} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const Counter = ({
  value, 
  onIncrement,
  onDecrement
}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <button onClick={onIncrement}> Plus </button>
      <button onClick={onDecrement}> Minus </button>
    </div>
  )
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need the provider and connect components from react-redux

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: you don't need <Provider /> or `connect()` for the examples OP is working on https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component won't re-render.

AFAIK, simply because a re-render can only be triggered if a component’s state or props has changed.

You need to trigger the your `App` component re-render inside store subscribe. I see your  store subscribe basically do nothing, only logging here.

```
store.subscribe(()=>{
  console.log(store.getState());
});
```

you could do something like this, to trigger re-render every time redux store updated:

```
const page = document.getElementById('page');
const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, page);
render();
store.subscribe(render);
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### The reason:

In your case, the component has no idea about the changes in the redux store and therefore it doesn't re-render.

Components are only re-rendering if they receiv new props/context 
or if their local state has updated (as a result of calling `setState()` in general)

---

### Solution 1 (direct answer to your question, I think)

```
const Counter = ({ value, onIncrement, onDecrement }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <button onClick={onIncrement}> Plus</button>
      <button onClick={onDecrement}> Minus</button>
    </div>
  )
};


class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsub = store.subscribe(this._update);
    this._update();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsub();
    this._unsub = null;
  };

  state = { value: undefined };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Counter Application</h1>

        <Counter
          value={value}
          onIncrement={this._increment}
          onDecrement={this._decrement}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  _decrement = () => store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' });

  _increment = () => store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });

  _update = () => {
    const value = store.getState();
    this.setState({ value });
  }
}
```

---

### Solution 2 (the correct one)

Use `react-redux` module

> Also check these:
>   - [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)
>   - [normalizr + keyWindow concept talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thW0yrj3sKU)
>   - [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)
>   - [ComputingDerivedData Post](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)
>   - [react-reselect-and-redux post](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-reselect-and-redux-b34017f8194c)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { _valueSelector1, _valueSelector2 } from 'app/feature/selectors';
import { increment, decrement } from 'app/feature/actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  valueOne: _valueSelector1(state, props),
  valueTwo: _valueSelector2(state, props),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  increment,
  decrement,
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export class YourComponent extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    valueOne: PropTypes.number,
    valueTwo: PropTypes.number,
    increment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    decrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const { valueOne, valueTwo, increment, decrement } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{valueOne}</span>
        <Counter value={valueTwo} onIncrement={increment} onDecrement={decrement} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```